# Chrome firing two OPTIONS requests on CORS preflight

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, cors

When doing CORS requests that require preflight, they fail to work on our network. Instead of Chrome making two requests, the `OPTIONS` and `PUT`, it fires two `OPTIONS` requests that are exactly the same, this ends up in the following error:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://server/api/foo. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)`

Digging into the problem, there are two things that stand out.

1. If I turn on Throttling in the Network section of the Chrome developer tools, things work and the `OPTIONS` request is followed by a `PUT`.
2. Under the timing tab, it almost looks like as if it tries to fire both ([First request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZLDF.png), 
   [Second request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFznU.png)) requests simultaneously. Despite the fact that a request is queued at a later time, the Started At time shows it at the same request as the initial `OPTIONS` request.

The throttled working, and non-working requests look fairly similar for [comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PD3Rm.png).

Comment: Have you tested the request in other browsers and does it work? The error message shown in the question indicates the response to the OPTIONS request is some kind of 3xx redirect, which causes the preflight to fail. The response to a preflight OPTIONS request must be a 2xx success response. If it’s a 3xx, all browsers treat that as a preflight failure (because that’s what the spec requires). So it seems like regardless of whatever other problem you’re having, you need to fix the problem of the server responding to the preflight with a redirect instead of a 2xx success.

Comment: Thanks. The redirect hint gave me a better idea of where to look. The issue seemed to be in an extension doing some strange redirects in the background, but apparently completely hiding them from the rest of the browser. If I ran it in incognito mode it worked as expected.