# Seemingly random "Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)"

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api2

I'm running into a problem with a seemingly random CORS error message. This will work 99 times out of 100 on the same call, with different parameters. And the next time I try a call with the same parameter that had previously thrown the `Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)` will succeed.  And it occurs on nearly every API call I have at one point or another.

I managed to capture one of these errors, and I'm trying to figure out why it is happening.

The login occurs in an Angular service:

```
login(UserId: string, password: string) {

const formData = {
  'username': UserId,
  'password': password
};

const headers = new HttpHeaders();

headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

return this.http.post<AuthResult>(environment.apiUrl + '/Authorization', formData, { headers: headers })
  .map(authResult => {
   if (authResult && authResult.Succeeded && authResult.Token) {
     // handle results here
   } else {
     console.error(`Error: ${authResult.ErrorMessage}`);
  })
  .do(response => console.log('Login method finished in Auth Service.'));
}
```

Results in the error in the Chrome console:

```
Failed to load http://localhost:12711/api/Authorization: Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)  :4200/#/login:1
```

And the subscriber to the returned observable going into the `onError` code block.

The odd part is that looking at a Fiddler trace shows that the server responds with a proper CORS response, with no redirects:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:12711/api/Authorization HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:12711
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:4200
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.119 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcUFhHOTA1MlxEb2N1bWVudHNcVlNQcm9qZWN0c1xDYXJlT3B0aW1pemF0aW9uU2VydmljZXNcQ2FyZU9wdGltaXphdGlvblNlcnZpY2VzXGFwaVxBdXRob3JpemF0aW9u?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 16 Mar 2018 15:53:47 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

I should note that this one in particular is a POST, but I've gotten the same error on GET. I just haven't captured one of those in Fiddler yet.

The fact that 99% of my API calls work just fine tells me that CORS is configured correctly. (I think!)

Why is Angular telling me there is a preflight redirect issue when there isn't a redirect returned? And why is it seemingly random where it will work regularly but fail on rare occasions?

I'm looking at Angular as the issue right now, because it looks to me that the API is returning the correct headers for CORS.

Details:

- Angular: 4.4.4
- Node: 9.4.0
- OS: win32 x64

I'm running (for testing) in my development environment. The Angular 4 app is running with "ng serve" and the API is running in Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise.  The API is a REST API written in C# with Web API 2.

These errors also occur in deployed environments. Again 99% of the API calls work fine there, and only 1% fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out what was happening and fix it with the help of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48081344/chrome-firing-two-options-requests-on-cors-preflight).  A Chrome extension (Digital Guardian) was causing Chrome to simultaneously send two OPTIONS requests on every CORS preflight. Once I had the extension removed, everything worked as expected.